# EEA Family permit application... please help

Tags: united-kingdom, immigration, eu, eu-citizens, eu-spouses

[image]

My wife is filling our her EEa FP and on the EEA National page there is this question "what is your permanent residential address and contact details" my question is who's address do we put there the EEA'S national address or my wife address. Also what should be put for the following question. Thank you

Comment: Hello Maciej I just noticed that you haven't accepted any of my answers for your questions.  You can do so by clicking the check mark seen below the voting buttons for the answer.  For more information, please read http://expatriates.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer.  Thanks!

Comment: Ok I think I did it let me no if I did something wrong so I can try it over

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The page refers elsewhere to "the EEA national" in the third person.  One is therefore tempted to conclude that the second person ("you") refers to the applicant.

However, I used this form a little over a year ago, and I remember that it's truly awful.  If I recall correctly, there are places where "you" is clearly used (improperly, in my opinion) to refer to the EEA national.  It is also difficult to give too much credence to grammar-based arguments regarding an application that asks ungrammatical questions like

> - What is your permanent residential address and contact details?
> - Are your correspondence address different ... ?
> - Does EEA national currently living in UK?

When I filled out this form, I resolved several ambiguities by making reference to the paper form: https://www.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/270530/vaf5.pdf.

That form asks for contact details for the EEA national, including permanent home address and correspondence address.  This supports the conclusion that the page you are asking about seeks that information as well.

If there's no other place in the online application that seeks the EEA national's address, then I would conclude that the screen you show implements section 8.3 of the paper application, and you should enter the EEA national's address.

In the unlikely event that you want to take time to be a test case, you can fill it out with the applicant's address.  Take a screen shot of the page with the applicant's information.  Submit that with your application to show that you had reason to believe that you were being asked for the applicant's address.

Comment: Thank you. They didn't ask anywhere else about my address just for my wife. But following that there are few questions about monthly expenses and who is the owner  of the house but it also ask "your"... so it's very confusing

Comment: @Maciej I don't think they're actually supposed to be asking about the financies.  As you can see on the paper application, you're supposed to skip 8.10.1 through 8.10.10 if the EEA national is already in the UK.  Yet another example of an extremely poor implementation of the web forms. Under the EU directive, I don't think they're supposed to be asking the information about finances at all, actually, unless perhaps the EEA national is "qualifying" as self-sufficient.

Comment: Well we did that application and my Jesus so much stupid questions... one question ask what job will my wife have in the UK and wat position and work it undertaken , I don't no eyey want us to answer that if she not even here working as yet. But thank you very much for all your help

Comment: @Maciej I wish you the best of luck.  You may need it; I've found much information online about improper denials of EEA FP applications, including on the grounds of marriage of convenience in cases where couples had one or two children together.  I think it depends a lot on the quality of the ECO who handles your application; such denials are in direct conflict with the government's guidance.  Please post a comment once you get a response to let us know what happens.

Comment: my wife went to the embassy yesterday (Barbados) she went with all our original documents they told her she could not submit the original so she had to make copies of everything and they sent her back with the origina they did not even take the original marriage certificate. Will that be a problem?

Comment: @Maciej As long as they have copies of everything it shouldn't matter that they didn't keep the originals.

Comment: thank you well we have a 15 days wait so I will let you know the outcome

Comment: we received an email stating the application was successfully and my wife should receive her documents in the following days. Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: @Maciej congratulations!